# GET direct_messages using url in Twitter

Tags: php, twitter

There is a requirement in an application in which we use only URL to access information on twitter. We cannot use twitter API for that. I have a reference URL : https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/direct_messages/sent but it is not working as it needs authentication.

Is there some other way to access it using URL only? I want to list all Direct messages of an account on twitter in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it requires Authentication then the only way you'll be able to "get" it using GET is to authenticate the user. Otherwise you'll see an error code in the response. Recent changes were made in the applications permission model for Direct Messages.

[Lean More Here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/application-permission-model)

Your going to need some code besides a URL to send, receive and validate authentication tokens.